# Why does Django add constraint when using Foreign Key instead of defining it in Create statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I'm going through the Django tutorial and am defining the poll and choice models. When I run `manage.py sql polls` to see the sql statements, I get:

```
CREATE TABLE `polls_poll` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `question` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `pub_date` datetime NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `polls_choice` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `poll_id` integer NOT NULL,
    `choice_text` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `votes` integer NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE `polls_choice` ADD CONSTRAINT `poll_id_refs_id_3aa09835`
    FOREIGN KEY (`poll_id`) REFERENCES `polls_poll` (`id`);
```

Why does Django use an `ALTER` statement when applying the Foreign Key instead of doing it in the `Create table` statement? Something like the following seems more succinct:

```
`poll_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES polls_choice(id)`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid dependency problems and circular references. For example, imagine two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE parent ( id, first_child_id );
CREATE TABLE child ( id, parent_id );
```

At least one of the references between `parent` and `child` must be added after the tables have been defined.

Now, because MySQL isn't particularly careful with referential integrity, this isn't a problem:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE parent ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, first_child_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES child(id) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

But more pedantic database engines will complain:

```
test=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
test=# SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
SET CONSTRAINTS
test=# CREATE TABLE parent (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, first_child_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES child(id));
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "parent_pkey" for table "parent"
ERROR:  relation "child" does not exist
```

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer! Makes perfect sense.